# determine residuals and outliers

Tags: r, performance

For my internship I have to perform certain analysis to determine residuals and outliers. The table I'm currently using has over 12 million records with 130+ columns.

My first tests take approx. 5398 seconds or 1.5 hours to apply the module and establish outliers and put them into a plot. The goal of my project is performing analysis on 14-20 similar models within an hour (on a better server, though).

I just changed the `glm()` to `lm()` and the process time went down from 1.5hr to 15 minutes.

I also got the following details from `Rprof()`:

> ```
>   $by.self
>                           self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
>   "lm.fit"                   920.64    99.16     921.56     99.26
>   ".Call"                      1.48     0.16       1.48      0.16
>   "plot.xy"                    1.22     0.13       1.22      0.13
>   ".External2"                 1.10     0.12       1.52      0.16
>   "colnames<-"                 0.92     0.10       0.92      0.10
>   ".External"                  0.88     0.09       0.88      0.09
>   "as.character"               0.66     0.07       0.66      0.07
>   "unique.default"             0.18     0.02       0.24      0.03
>   "strsplit"                   0.18     0.02       0.18      0.02
>   "[.data.frame"               0.16     0.02       0.18      0.02
>   "match"                      0.12     0.01       0.12      0.01
>   "sort.int"                   0.12     0.01       0.12      0.01
>   "Determine_bounds"           0.08     0.01     927.86     99.94
>   "na.omit"                    0.08     0.01       0.42      0.05
>   "FUN"                        0.08     0.01       0.34      0.04
>   "na.omit.data.frame"         0.08     0.01       0.34      0.04
>   "is.na"                      0.08     0.01       0.08      0.01
>   "is.factor"                  0.06     0.01       0.06      0.01
>   "lapply"                     0.04     0.00       0.38      0.04
>   "anyNA"                      0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
>   "readLines"                  0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
>   "model.matrix.default"       0.02     0.00       1.24      0.13
>   "model.response"             0.02     0.00       0.68      0.07
>   "anyDuplicated.default"      0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   "as.double"                  0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   "lazyLoadDBfetch"            0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   "max"                        0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   "pmatch"                     0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   "table"                      0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>   $by.total
>                           total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
>   "Determine_bounds"          927.86     99.94      0.08     0.01
>   "main"                      927.86     99.94      0.00     0.00
>   "lm"                        924.00     99.53      0.00     0.00
>   "lm.fit"                    921.56     99.26    920.64    99.16
>   ".External2"                  1.52      0.16      1.10     0.12
>   ".Call"                       1.48      0.16      1.48     0.16
>   "dbGetQuery"                  1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "DbQuery"                     1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "doTryCatch"                  1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   ".local"                      1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   ".oci.GetQuery"               1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "standardGeneric"             1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "try"                         1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "tryCatch"                    1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "tryCatchList"                1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "tryCatchOne"                 1.48      0.16      0.00     0.00
>   "plot"                        1.26      0.14      0.00     0.00
>   "plot.default"                1.26      0.14      0.00     0.00
>   "model.matrix.default"        1.24      0.13      0.02     0.00
>   "model.matrix"                1.24      0.13      0.00     0.00
>   "plot.xy"                     1.22      0.13      1.22     0.13
>   "colnames<-"                  0.92      0.10      0.92     0.10
>   ".External"                   0.88      0.09      0.88     0.09
>   "dev.off"                     0.84      0.09      0.00     0.00
>   "model.response"              0.68      0.07      0.02     0.00
>   "as.character"                0.66      0.07      0.66     0.07
>   "summaryRprof"                0.52      0.06      0.00     0.00
>   "<Anonymous>"                 0.44      0.05      0.00     0.00
>   "eval"                        0.44      0.05      0.00     0.00
>   "model.frame.default"         0.44      0.05      0.00     0.00
>   "na.omit"                     0.42      0.05      0.08     0.01
>   "lapply"                      0.38      0.04      0.04     0.00
>   "FUN"                         0.34      0.04      0.08     0.01
>   "na.omit.data.frame"          0.34      0.04      0.08     0.01
>   "unique.default"              0.24      0.03      0.18     0.02
>   "factor"                      0.20      0.02      0.00     0.00
>   "strsplit"                    0.18      0.02      0.18     0.02
>   "[.data.frame"                0.18      0.02      0.16     0.02
>   "["                           0.18      0.02      0.00     0.00
>   "quantile"                    0.16      0.02      0.00     0.00
>   "quantile.default"            0.16      0.02      0.00     0.00
>   "match"                       0.12      0.01      0.12     0.01
>   "sort.int"                    0.12      0.01      0.12     0.01
>   "sort"                        0.12      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "sort.default"                0.12      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "is.na"                       0.08      0.01      0.08     0.01
>   "as.factor"                   0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "diff"                        0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   ".getXlevels"                 0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "IQR"                         0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "levels"                      0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "unique"                      0.08      0.01      0.00     0.00
>   "is.factor"                   0.06      0.01      0.06     0.01
>   "anyNA"                       0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
>   "readLines"                   0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
>   "pdf"                         0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "sapply"                      0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "anyDuplicated.default"       0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "as.double"                   0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "lazyLoadDBfetch"             0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "max"                         0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "pmatch"                      0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "table"                       0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
>   "anyDuplicated"               0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "deparse"                     0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   ".deparseOpts"                0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "paste"                       0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "range"                       0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   "xy.coords"                   0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
>   $sample.interval        [1] 0.02
>   $sampling.time      [1] 928.4
> ```

The R code:

```
 #include libraries
 library(DBI)
 library(ROracle)
 library(outliers)
 library(Rmisc)
 library(data.table)
 #set params
 options(width=10000, error=traceback)
 args <- commandArgs()
 #print(args)
 debug <-F

 ### Connect to database
 drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
 con <- dbConnect(drv, username="DB USER", password="DB PASS", dbname="DB NAME")



 main <- function(){
         #Data_table  = "BPM_FINISHING_DATA"
         Data_table = "TBL_TRAINING_SET"
         print(paste("Performing queries against", Data_table))
         AllTraits = "BACKFAT_CARCASS"
                 if(debug){cat("\n\n")}
                 ptm <- proc.time()
         a <- Determine_bounds(Data_table)
                 tijd <- proc.time() - ptm
                 cat("\n")
                 cat(paste("\t",tijd['elapsed'][1]))



 }


 Determine_bounds <- function(Data_table){
         ### Create query
         sqlstr <- paste("
                 select PIG_ID,
                         coalesce(to_char(trial_tstart), to_char(trial_tmed), to_char(trial_tend)) \"trial\",
                         bln_tend_sex_lgp_itn \"farm_tend\",
                         gain_tstart_tend \"gain\",
                         BREEDING_LINE,
                         SEX_CODE,
                         bln_cmt_tstart_itn \"farmcomp\",
                         --coalesce(bln_cmt_tstart_itn, hys_birth_tend, HYS_CGG) \"farmcomp\",
                         birth_weight_scaled
                 from
                         ",Data_table,"
                where
                         EBT_TSTART = 'Y'
                         AND EBT_TEND = 'Y'
                 ")
         if(Data_table == "BPM_FINISHING_DATA"){
                 sqlstr <- paste(sqlstr, " AND FINISHER_YN = 'N'")
         }

         cat(format(sqlstr))
         ### Run query against database
         res <- DbQuery(sqlstr)
         res$trial[is.na(res$trial)] <-"XXX"
         res$farm_trend[is.null(res$farm_trend)] <- -9
         res$birth_weight_scaled[is.null(res$birth_weight_scaled)] <- -9


         lmfit = lm(res$gain ~ res$trial + res$farm_trend * res$BREEDING_LINE* res$SEX_CODE + res$birth_weigh    t_scaled)#+res$farmcomp)

         kwant <- quantile(resid(lmfit), probs= c(0.25, 0.75))
         Q1 <- kwant[1]
         Q3 <- kwant[2]
         sigma <- IQR(resid(lmfit))
         upp_multi <- 3.5        ##Amount of times sigma for outlier calculation
         low_multi <- 1.5        ##Amount of times sigma for outlier calculation

         upp_fence <- Q3+(upp_multi * sigma)
         low_fence <- Q1-(low_multi * sigma)
         print(paste("Upper fence: ", upp_fence, " \t  Lower Fence: ", low_fence ,"\n"))



        pdf('~/scripts/PlotResiduals.pdf')
        plot(resid(lmfit),ylim=c(low_fence*2,upp_fence *2), axes=F )
        title(main="Outliers", sub="X axis title")
        abline(h= upp_fence, col="blue")
        abline(h= low_fence, col="red")
            dev.off()






 }


 DbQuery <- function(sqlstr){
         res <- dbGetQuery(con, sqlstr)
         return(res)
 }

 main()
 dbDisconnect(con)

 q()
```

Right now I've scripted the following code and I was wondering. Where could the code below be improved the most? (I know I'm not the best coder, but always trying to learn and improve.)

I am currently reading [these](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) [two](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2010/BioC2010/EfficientRProgramming.pdf) PDFs about performance but I'd still like some feedback.

Comment: There is a technique called "profiling", which you can use to find out which parts of your code are actually consuming most of the time. Learn that technique. See `help("Rprof")` and several packages for the R part of your code.

Comment: Thank you @Roland ! Will give it a try, I was actually just reading about it :)

Comment: try `lm` instead of `glm` ?

Comment: or even `lm.fit` if you only need the residuals

Comment: I'd look at optimizing the sql queries. You should (probably?) have some sort of client to explain the query you are trying to run. Start there. The transformations you are doing could potentially be faster in data.table (which you are loading anyway)

Comment: @erasmortg I need every little bit of that query. Which transformations dyou think could be improved? :)

Comment: @erasmortg I considered splitting up the query into pieces to reduce memory load, but I need the retrieved data as a whole to calculate the residuals :(

Comment: @Heuer What is your 'coalesce' doing? I can't seem to identify any expression in particular (other than to_char). You could retrieve those and perhaps pass by reference in R? Perhaps using a subquery to index first on your where statement. If you think retrieving pieces first could be faster, try so and then try to bind_rows in R

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, time has already been reduced to 15 minutes using lm

Comment: @Erasmortg the 'Coalesce' grabs the first of the three columns that contains data. The "to_char" could probably be removed, I took that part from our other query as I didn't knew what coalesce was before. In which way do you think I could index the statement, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Also reading more about bind_rows now. Also looking at the Rprof() data in my edited question I think the bottleneck is lm(), and not the query!

Comment: For further speedup you could try `RcppArmadillo::fastLm` (see [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-linear-model-with-armadillo/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420185/fastlm-is-much-slower-than-lm))

Comment: The CRAN High-Performance Tasks Views (https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) mention the `speedglm` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/index.html). Worth a try. Note how it says "High performances
can be obtained especially if R is linked against an optimized BLAS, such as ATLAS". You will find many articles showing you how to do that if you google `R blas atlas`.

Comment: I'll point you to these results http://www.avrahamadler.com/2014/04/20/r-3-1-0-openblas-speed-comparisons showing how switching from the default blas shipped with R to OpenBLAS improved this person's `qr` decomposition (what lm uses) computation times by a factor of ~4 (from 417 to 113 ms). So regardless of whether you choose to try `speedglm` (my other suggestion), it is definitely worth looking into what blas you are currently using and possibly switching to a better one.

Comment: @flodel Thank you for the feedback, trying to get speedglm working atm and will switch my BLAS to Atlas soon!

Comment: @Flodel, if you create your comment about the HPC as answer I will accept it, you can't believe how much it helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

Comment by [@flodel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16479/flodel):

> The [CRAN High-Performance Tasks Views](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) mention [the `speedglm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/index.html). It is Worth a try. Note how it says "High performances
> can be obtained especially if R is linked against an optimized BLAS, such as ATLAS". You will find many articles showing you how to do that if you google `R blas atlas`.
>
> I'll point you to  [these results](http://www.avrahamadler.com/2014/04/20/r-3-1-0-openblas-speed-comparisons) showing how switching from the default blas shipped with R to OpenBLAS improved this person's `qr` decomposition (what lm uses) computation times by a factor of ~4 (from 417 to 113 ms). So regardless of whether you choose to try `speedglm`, it is definitely worth looking into what blas you are currently using and possibly switching to a better one.

Comment: @flodel If you care to repost this answer under your own name, we can delete this placeholder.